# Is it possible to watch interrupts on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, cpu, computer-architecture, interrupts

With my linux box I can do the following to watch interrupts live:

`watch -n1 "cat /proc/interrupts"`

Is there a way to do this on Windows systems, especially Windows 7?

Comment: Have a look for the Windows 7 SDK, and then Google for monitoring DPCs. I think that'll be a good start.

Comment: XPerf from the Windows Performance Toolkit.

Answer (score 2):

I can only speak for XP, which is what I have.

On XP, I don't know a way to watch them real time, but there is the next best thing, which is logging the events for a time, and then looking at the produced log file results.

The program to do this is RATT - it's a Microsoft produced tool, that's really light weight, and clearly aimed at developers. Not that tough to use though, and it does the job.

(Used it very recently myself to diagnose a problem with excessive hardware interrupts constantly taking 25-40% of my CPU processing power. Helped me identify a defective driver that was sending insane amounts of hardware interrupts, and fix the problem. )